# Creating multi-level alphabetical folder structure in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a short script to organise several thousand files into alphabetical folders, an arbitrary number of levels deep. This is to allow the tree to be browsed on the old hardware (e.g. an Amiga 500) without the number of files in any given folder locking up the UI.

E.g. The file 'abacus' would go in:

/A/AB/ABA/abacus

'triangle' in:

/T/TR/TRI/triangle

I'd like to specify the depth as a single variable so I can try different numbers of levels. Three might turn out to be too little or too many.

I'm struggling with the necessary recursion to create the initial folder structure. I can get the names and locations of the source files,  create new folders and traverse up and down the tree with the os library (respectively walk, mkdir, path.dirname/path.join), have worked out how to copy the files to their respective right places and to delete unused folders after the copy (e.g. the '/C/CF/CFZ' path is unlikely to end up with any files in it, assuming all the file names are English words). But I'm going round in circles on the initial step.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is probably a much more elegant way of doing this, but this should work:

```
import os
import itertools

depth = 3

#create the base directory
basepath = '/path/to/alphabet'
os.mkdir(basepath)

#setup alphabet list
#long to crate full directory structure
#alphabet = 'A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z'  
alphabet = 'A B C'   #short alphabet for testing purposes
alphabet = alphabet.split()

#helper variable for determining what depth you are at
c_depth = alphabet

#create depth 0
for letter in alphabet:
    #print letter
    pth = os.path.join(basepath,letter)
    os.mkdir(pth)

#
for d in range(depth-1):
    #take the cartesian product of your current directories and your alphabet
    #in order to obtain all possible permutations. Will return tuples like
    #('AAA','B')
    result = list(itertools.product(*(alphabet,c_depth)))
    #print d

    #reset the current directory list
    cdirs = []

    #for each directory at the new depth
    for elem in result:

        #create the full name by joining tuples created previously
        dName =  ''.join(itertools.chain(elem))

        #build up path where it belongs from the letters it is comprised of
        pth = basepath
        for l in range(len(dName)-1):
            pth = os.path.join(pth,dName[:l+1])

        #add the new directory folder to the end of the path
        pth = os.path.join(pth,dName)

        #make new directory
        os.mkdir(pth)
        #print dName
        cdirs.append(dName)

    #reset helper variable
    c_depth = cdirs
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer and intro to itertools more generally. Although it's longer than Thmei Esi's, this is the one I used as it works with Python 3 below 3.5 (I want this to work with the system version of Python 3 in OpenSuse 42.1, which is 3.4.5).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more elegant version:

```
import os
import itertools

depth = 3

#create the base directory
basepath = 'alphabet'
os.mkdir(basepath)

#setup alphabet list
#alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
alphabet = 'ABC'   #short alphabet for testing purposes

current_path = [basepath]

def create_hierarchy(max_depth, current_path, current_depth=0):
    if current_depth < max_depth:
        for i in alphabet:
            newfolder = (''.join(current_path[-1]) + i) if current_depth != 0 else i
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(*current_path, newfolder))
            create_hierarchy(max_depth, current_path + [newfolder], current_depth + 1)
    else:
        return

create_hierarchy(depth, current_path)
```

It is adapted from user3235916's answer.

Comment: Thank you. This ran very quickly but as per comment on user3235916's answer, it needs Python 3.5+ due to line "os.mkdir(os.path.join(*current_path, newfolder))" - positional arguments are not allowed after *expression below 3.5 (apparently).

Answer (score 0):

itertools.combinations(iterable, r) may help

I'm just showing the 1st 5 alphas, different r
building your directory names should be easy from combinations() output
 (it returns a generator, requiring the * in the print)

```
import string
from itertools import combinations

print(*combinations(string.ascii_uppercase[0:5], 2), sep='\n')
('A', 'B')
('A', 'C')
('A', 'D')
('A', 'E')
('B', 'C')
('B', 'D')
('B', 'E')
('C', 'D')
('C', 'E')
('D', 'E')

print(*combinations(string.ascii_uppercase[0:5], 3), sep='\n')
('A', 'B', 'C')
('A', 'B', 'D')
('A', 'B', 'E')
('A', 'C', 'D')
('A', 'C', 'E')
('A', 'D', 'E')
('B', 'C', 'D')
('B', 'C', 'E')
('B', 'D', 'E')
('C', 'D', 'E')

print(*combinations(string.ascii_uppercase[0:5], 4), sep='\n')
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
('A', 'B', 'C', 'E')
('A', 'B', 'D', 'E')
('A', 'C', 'D', 'E')
('B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
```